# "can't open camera by index" using cv2 on Linux

Tags: python, linux

I am trying to make a motion detector (using the internal camera) in python(3), I am using linux (debian), and I keep getting this error

```
[ WARN:0@0.724] global /io/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_v4l.cpp (889) open VIDEOIO(V4L2:/dev/video0): can't open camera by index
```

here's the code I'm using

```
from imutils.video import VideoStream
import argparse
import datetime
import imutils
import time
import cv2

ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-v", "--video", help="")
ap.add_argument("-a", "--min-area", type=int, default=500, help="minimum area size")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

if args.get("video", None) is None:
    vs = VideoStream(src=0).start()
    time.sleep(2.0)

else:
    vs = cv2.VideoCapture(args["Video"])

firstFrame = None

while True:

    frame = vs.read()
    frame = frame if args.get("video", None) is None else frame[1]
    text = "Muon is stuck in helium"

    if frame is None:
        break
    
    frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=500)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (21, 21), 0)
    
    if firstFrame is None:
        firstFrame = gray
        continue

    frameDelta = cv2.absdiff(firstFrame, gray)
    thresh = cv2.threshold(frameDelta, 25, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

    thresh = cv2.dilate(thresh, None, iterations=2)
    cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
        cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)
    
    for c in cnts:
        
        if cv2.contourArea(c) < args["min_area"]:
            continue

        (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
        text = "Muon is fusing hydrogen"
        
    cv2.putText(frame, "Room Status: {}".format(text), (10, 20),
        cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 0, 255), 2)
    cv2.putText(frame, datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%A %d %B %Y %I:%M:%S%p"),
        (10, frame.shape[0] - 10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.35, (0, 0, 255), 1)

    cv2.imshow("Security Feed", frame)
    cv2.imshow("Thresh", thresh)
    cv2.imshow("Frame Delta", frameDelta)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

    if key == ord("q"):
        break

vs.stop() if args.get("video", None) is None else vs.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

personally, I think that the problem is linux is having trouble using the internal camera,  but I ofc have been wrong before, but if that is the problem, can somebody please help me fix it, and if it isn't, can somebody please help me out, and tell me what I need to fix please

Comment: Can you use your webcam from other software running as the same user account? Note that general Linux troubleshooting is off-topic here -- you should have problems not related to the specific piece of software you're writing solved before asking your question; if you have trouble with that, [unix.se] is a better place to start.

Comment: (the first thing to check is just permissions; are you running as a user account with permission to connect to the camera? Which user and group is the device owned by if you run `ls -l /dev/video0`? If it's in a group other than `root`, is that group listed when you run the command `groups`? What are the permission bits on the device entry? etc).